# titlesec section formating with rules

Tags: titlesec

This is a rather specific question I have had for years now but I always just implemented a crummy manual solution.

I want my section headings to look like this. That being the section is in small caps (which has a rule on both sides)

```
                      -------------A CENTERED SECTION------------
```

The following causes this, with the after-rule not in the same line.

```
                      -------------A CENTERED SECTION
                   ------------

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\color{theblue}\centering\bfseries\scshape\Huge}{}{0in}{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{2in}{0.5pt}}}[\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{2in}{0.5pt}}]
```

And this change produces the proper structure, but it is not centered.

```
 -------------A NOT CENTERED SECTION------------

\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\color{theblue}\centering\bfseries\scshape\Huge}{}{0in}{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{2in}{0.5pt}}}[\raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{2in}{0.5pt}}\newline]
```

Another curriosity is that the other shape options seem to break all the formatting content, even the color.

For reference, from titlesec.pdf

\titleformat{
〈
command
〉
}[
〈
shape
〉
]{
〈
format
〉
}{
〈
label
〉
}{
〈
sep
〉
}{
〈
before-code
〉
}[
〈
after-code
〉
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With   two rules 2 inches long, your title must be really short  to make everything fit on a line (or your paper sheet very wide)!

Anyway, here is a possibility with rules 1.5 in long, only `\huge` size, and the `block` style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\filcenter\color{SteelBlue}\centering\bfseries\scshape\huge}{\rule[0.5ex]{1.5in}{0.5pt}}{0.5em}{#1\enspace \rule[0.5ex]{1.5in}{0.5pt}}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

 \section{A Test Section}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am confused, why did you use {} instead of [] for the after-code?

Comment: I think I see what you did. Instead you used the label section in place of before-code and the before-code section in place of after-code.

Comment: @Bob: I didn't really use any after-code: I only used the 4th argument of `\titleformat`, anf the `explicit` optionsq lets me write the code for a small rule after the title.